# Running Docker For Windows on a Virtualbox VM

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to run Docker for windows on a Virtualbox VM (Windows 2016) and my host is a Linux Machine

On the VM settings Hardware Virtualization is enabled (VT-x/AMD-V)

but I'm getting the following error

> "Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must
>   be enabled in the BIOS"

Is this setup even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar working environment but usinh Hyper-V On Windows Server 2016 and a Debian VM.

However, in virtualbox check also "PAE/NX" and Nested VT-x in the "CPU/Processor" tab.

Comment: The checkbox **Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V** is grayed out for me